# Postinf two images url to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am struggling to add the second url to the database. I've tried couple other approaches and didn't get far. I have tried uploading each individually but then it was creating two children. I ended up following the answer from [Upload Multiple Images on Firebase - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319996/upload-multiple-images-on-firebase-android-studio) and here I am.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
 posts
      -LRTx-3WJNP2zxifv7h9
         city:
         contact_email:
         country:
         description:
         image:  URL IMAGE IN STORAGE
         image1:  URL IMAGE1 IN STORAGE
         post_id:
         price:
         state_province:
         title:
         user_id:
```

Both images were uploaded successfully to storage, but I only get one url in my database like below: 
image1 is not present.

```
posts
      -LRTx-3WJNP2zxifv7h9
         city:
         contact_email:
         country:
         description:
         image:  URL IMAGE IN STORAGE
         post_id:
         price:
         state_province:
         title:
         user_id:
```

Code:

```
if( mSelectedUri !=null ){

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

final String postId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().getKey();

StorageReference filepath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("posts/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()+
                "/" + postId + "/post_image").child(mSelectedUri.getLastPathSegment());

StorageReference filepath1 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("posts/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() +
                "/" + postId + "/post_image1").child(mSelectedUri1.getLastPathSegment());




filepath.putFile(mSelectedUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


        Uri firebaseUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        Post post = new Post();
        post.setImage(firebaseUri.toString());
      //  post.setImage1(firebaseUri.toString());

        post.setCity(mCity.getText().toString());
        post.setContact_email(mContactEmail.getText().toString());
        post.setCountry(mCountry.getText().toString());
        post.setDescription(mDescription.getText().toString());
        post.setPost_id(postId);
        post.setPrice(mPrice.getText().toString());
        post.setState_province(mStateProvince.getText().toString());
        post.setTitle(mTitle.getText().toString());
        post.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

        reference.child(getString(R.string.node_posts))
                .child(postId)
                .setValue(post);



    }


});




filepath1.putFile(mSelectedUri1).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


        Uri firebaseUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        Post post = new Post();
        post.setImage1(firebaseUri.toString());

        reference.child(getString(R.string.node_posts))
                .child(postId)
                .setValue(post);

       // resetFields();



    }


});
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things to remember:

1) Firebase listeners are not synchronous in nature. The sequence in which you have written the listeners may not be followed.

2) When you write in a location in Firebase, it will replace the previous entire object with the new one.

Right now, your filepath1 onSuccessListener executes first. After that, the filepath onSuccessListener executes which overwrites whatever the filepath1 onSuccessListener wrote in the database. That is why you are getting this result. You can check for yourself by looking at your database when you execute this command.

Try out this code. It should solve your problem.

```
if( mSelectedUri !=null ){

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

final String postId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().getKey();

StorageReference filepath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("posts/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()+
                "/" + postId + "/post_image").child(mSelectedUri.getLastPathSegment());

StorageReference filepath1 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("posts/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() +
                "/" + postId + "/post_image1").child(mSelectedUri1.getLastPathSegment());
        Uri firebaseUri1;




filepath.putFile(mSelectedUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


    firebaseUri1 = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();






            filepath1.putFile(mSelectedUri1).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                    Uri firebaseUri2 = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                        Post post = new Post();
                        post.setImage(firebaseUri1.toString());
                      //  post.setImage1(firebaseUri.toString());

                        post.setCity(mCity.getText().toString());
                        post.setContact_email(mContactEmail.getText().toString());
                        post.setCountry(mCountry.getText().toString());
                        post.setDescription(mDescription.getText().toString());
                        post.setPost_id(postId);
                        post.setPrice(mPrice.getText().toString());
                        post.setState_province(mStateProvince.getText().toString());
                        post.setTitle(mTitle.getText().toString());
                        post.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        post.setImage1(firebaseUri2.toString());


                        reference.child(getString(R.string.node_posts))
                                .child(postId)
                                .setValue(post);



   // resetFields();



                }


});



    }


});
```

Comment: Thank you, I just made         Uri firebaseUri1;  and filepath1 Final and it works great

Comment: No probs! @SifaksAgizul